# Dynamic Bootstrap 4 Navbar "active" tag

Tags: javascript, php

i need to change the "active" class depending on the site you are right now when clicking the header.

Ive seen some examples using a php check if you are on the page "noten.php" and it would change the navbar class to active accordingly, also checked some Javascript like this

```
$('.navbar-nav .nav-link').click(function(){
$('.navbar-nav .nav-item').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

})
but nothing worked

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Projekt</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Startseite</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/noten.php">Noten</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Soon</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: _“Ive seen some examples of this but none worked”_ - that is pretty much useless info. Please go read [ask], and edit your question accordingly. Show us what you tried, and with what results.

Comment: You definitely want the PHP solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found a way.

Adding this at the top of my header include

```
<?php
$pg = basename(substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],0,strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.'))); // get file name from url and strip extension
```

?>

and then adding this to the Navbar itself

```
          <li class="nav-item <?php if($pg=='index'){?>active<?php }?>">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Startseite</a>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know much about your PHP logic, but the implementation may be pretty simple:

```
<?php
  $uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
  $uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);
?>


<li class="nav-item <?php echo 'active page-' . $uri_segments[0]; ?>">
  <a class="nav-link" href="/">Startseite</a>
</li>
```

For the url `http://foobar/first/second` will add the class `page-first`.